# how to attach multiple images to email using java application?

Tags: image, jsp, email

I have attach single image in my jsp application. But i couldn't be able to attach multiple image same using same way.

The code i have used+

[image]

Comment: What means "couldn't be able'?

Comment: i mean mean,i can't attach multiple images